# How to show the report of Linux perf record -g without call graph data?

Tags: linux, perf

I collected a performance profile of an application with `perf record -g`.

By default, `perf report` displays call chain data:

```
   100.00%     0.00%  htop     htop                [.] main
            |
            ---main
               |          
                --99.96%--ScreenManager_run
                          |          
                          |--98.98%--ProcessList_scan
```

Is that possible to produce Linux perf report as if I did not specify `-g` at the time of recording?

I.e., I would like my report look like this:

```
36.26%  htop     [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] __d_lookup
 5.65%  htop     [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] __d_lookup_rcu
 3.41%  htop     [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] pid_revalidate
 2.68%  htop     [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] _raw_spin_lock
```

Answer (score 3):

The recent versions of Linux perf allow to specify `none` as a "type" of a call chain. So, in order to achieve what you need, you should run `perf report` as follows:

```
perf report -g none --no-children ...
```

Note, that the documentation (`man perf report`) might not mention this option.